# how to reset a SOLR db?

Tags: java, lucene, solr

I need to reset my seacrh DB (still experimenting and do not want it to return trash).
Is it enough to simply remove all files from under the data/spellchecker and data/index directories?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its simple as removal of the data folder.

you can also use -

```
http://host:port/solr/core/update?stream.body=<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>
```

However, this would clean up the complete index with no backup.
So you may want to back it up before.

Answer (score 1):

You can post a delete query:

```
<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>
```

Answer (score 0):

To be precise, when using data import handler you should delete always dataimport.properties from "conf" directory.